# Safe Wallet with WalletConnect get me an error with waitForTransaction()

Tags: gnosis-safe, walletconnect, wagmi

When I call a writing function with my multisig Safe Wallet, I got an error when I call waitForTransaction() function:
"TransactionNotFoundError: Transaction with hash "0x396...5add475ab" could not be found."
This hash returned is the safeHash. Someone know how to get the Transaction hash?
The error appears after I click submit on the Safe Wallet.

Can someone help me please?